# failed update, now cannot remove, device or resource busy

Tags: upgrade, reinstall

Acer Chromebook C7

Trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.
Upgrade got interrupted and failed.
Now when trying to reinstall using crouton I find chroots directory is not empty.
Trying to remove folders and filesin chroots directory results in numerous "cannot remove, device or resource busy"